# What is the role of zener diode in this clipper circuit?

Tags: zener, voltage-clipping

[image]

i don't know exactly why we're adding the zener diode. My guess would be that it functions as a voltage regulator but that's as far as i can go.

Comment: It clips positive peaks to Vd + Vz. It passes negative peaks with no change but via 2.2k resistor. As the tiotle says, it is a positive clipper (only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Vo is positive, it clips at around 4.6v (3.9v zener + 0.7v diode). Above 4.6v, the zener and diode combined act like a clamp, conducting, to bring the voltage down. R drops the remaining voltage.

When Vo is negative, the diode blocks clipping. No current flows through the diodes. If no current is drawn to/from Vo then voltage across R is zero therefore Vo equals Vi

It's not much of a voltage regulator at all if AC is passed in. It is not possible to say what this circuit could be used for; it could be anything. But in short, it simply limits Vo to about +4.6v.

Comment: and why did we not just add another cell in place of zener?

Comment: Except that the zener is 3.9V. ;-)

Comment: Because a battery would be a very weird way of doing it - not that it would work well. Zener diodes are for clamping voltages. Batteries aren't. Batteries need replacing, zeners don't. +1 for the really weird idea though!

Comment: @dandavis the diode here actually prevents the bottom half being clipped. It would be clipped down to -0.7  without the diode

Comment: @Jodes - Interest only. A forward biased zener probably clips at a bit more than 0.7V in the forward direction. From some time ago now memory, 0.9V to over a volt.