# Hand crank voltage spike

Tags: voltage, batteries, capacitor, generator, charge

this is a follow up to my last question. I am working on a hand crank battery charger project. My current set up is that I am using a geared nema 17 stepper motor as a generator and have a bridge rectifier on each coil.  I have the both of the two rectified coils wired in parallel to get max current output. I also have a 25V 4700uf capacitor across each rectifier to stabilise the output. I then feed the rectified voltage into a buck/boost converter to step it down to 5V which is what my 18650 li-ion BMS requires.

However I notice that when I first turn the crank there is a 10V spike from the output of the buck/boost module before for about 1 second before it stabilises to 5V (slightly less under load).

My question is what is causing this and is it a problem for my BMS circuit? If so how can I avoid it?  I have a feeling it’s to do with that capacitors but I don’t know for sure. Help wound be much appreciated, happy to provide more details if need be.
Thanks
Billy.

Comment: What output voltage are you getting out of the stepper motor when you crank it? Can you put it on a scope and view the initial voltage whilst cranking and at steady state. What's the spec for the buck converter e.g. max input voltage? Perhaps you may need to clip a startup transient with a TVS before it gets to the buck converter.

Comment: @mhaselup I am getting about 15 volts DC from stepper after rectification. Unfortunately I don’t have access to a scope at the moment. I’m using the XL6009 35Vin max. Not sure what you mean by clip a startup transient with TVS. Do you mind explaining further please? Thanks.

Comment: You may get a high voltage spike when you start cranking, obviously without a scope it's hard to say. A transient voltage suppressor (tvs) or a zener setup could be used to clip voltage above 35v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the three items will help provide some context. I think you may still be able to use the buck converter approach with a zener voltage limiting front end on your circuit.

[What is the role of zener diode in this clipper circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300568/what-is-the-role-of-zener-diode-in-this-clipper-circuit/300572#300572)

[AC overvoltage protection for bike dynamo (alternator)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522273/ac-overvoltage-protection-for-bike-dynamo-alternator)

[Calculating max power of bicycle dynamo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325991/calculating-max-power-of-bicycle-dynamo/325998#325998)